# .NET ORMs and persisting non-property state

Tags: .net, orm, properties, class-design, private-members

I am just getting started with .NET ORMs, to the point where I haven't even decided between Entity Framework and NHibernate. But in both cases, I'm running into a problem in that they seem to want me to design my classes in various ways that seem unnatural. This is one of several questions on the subject.

---

Example class:

```
public class Pledge // this is an entity BTW, not a value object
{
    private readonly int initialAmount;
    private bool hasBeenDoubledYet;

    public Pledge(int initialAmount)
    {
        this.initialAmount = initialAmount;
    }

    public int GetCurrentAmount()
    {
        return this.hasBeenDoubledYet ? this.initialAmount * 2 : this.initialAmount;
    }
    public void Double()
    {
        this.hasBeenDoubledYet = true;
    }
}
```

In this case the persistence logic is a bit complicated. We would want to persist the private `initialAmount` and `hasBeenDoubledYet` fields; when re-instantiating, we would want to call the constructor with `initialAmount`, and call `Double()` if the `hasBeenDoubledYet` field is `true`. This is obviously something I'd have to write some code for.

On the other hand, the typical "ORM friendly" version of the code would probably end up looking more like this, as far as I understand:

```
public class Pledge
{
    // These are properties for persistence reasons
    private int InitialAmount { get; set; }  // only set in the constructor or if you are an ORM
    private bool HasBeenDoubledYet { get; set; }

    private Pledge() { } // for persistence
    public Pledge(int initialAmount) { /* as before but with properties */ }

    public int GetCurrentAmount() { /* as before but with properties */ }
    public int Double() { /* as before but with properties */ }
}
```

I covered my reservations about default constructors and readonly fields etc. in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364612/net-orms-immutable-value-objects-structs-default-constructors-and-readonly-p), but I guess this question is really about how I could get ORMs to handle private fields instead of private properties---can it be done in EF? In NHibernate? We can't mark fields `virtual` for proxying purposes... would marking the methods that use them `virtual` suffice?

---

It all feels so hacky :(. I am hoping that someone here can point out where I am wrong, either in my grasp of their capabilities or in my thinking about domain modeling and the role of ORMs.

Comment: it feels "hacky" because you are misusing what ORM is design for; you are trying to do business logic inside the entity object; some refs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-RM, I am sure there are many more if you do simple search

Comment: @K Ivanov: I admit I am a newbie at this, but this is meant to be an entity in the sense of domain-driven design, so business logic does indeed go there. I thought the ORMs job was to translate between the database and the domain objects. Are you saying there should be an intermediate layer of "entity objects" between the database and my domain layer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about EF, but NHibernate needs the properties you want to persist to be virtual and public (as you said for proxying reasons).